# What are some great books for beginning game programming?

Tags: graphics, directx, graphical-programming, managed-directx

I've been programming for a little over 2 years now, and I want to get started with graphics programming and make some simple games to start with. A lot of the books I've looked at for learning directx assume you know the basics of it, which I don't, or that they'll just give you some snippets and assume you'll be able to digest their cryptic code without an explanation. So what are some good books for somebody that is truly new to graphics programming but has a some knowledge with general programming?

Comment: You might find the answer (or a better response) here - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For some Direct3D 11 related book recommendations, see this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx) post.

Answer (score 0):

Hands down, the best 'graphics programming' book I have ever seen is "[An Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 9.0c: A Shader Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598220160)" by Frank Luna. It starts from the ground up with a linear algebra primer (absolutely critical), then explains how the 3D pipeline works (model, world, camera, ndc, view) and how to deal with the programming nightmare that is Directx ;)

It also covers some advanced techniques, suchs as reflections and refractions etc, but once you've gotten the essentials down (the first 8 chapters) you can basically write anything you want in directx and the rest of your graphics programming time will be spent reading books like the "Shader X" series by Wolfgang Engel, ([Shader X7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584505982) is particularly good), GPU Pro (same author), and Nvidia's GPU Gems, which they have on their website for free: [Gpu Gems](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/gpu_gems_home.html).

Answer (score 0):

Android NDK Game Development Cookbook [http://www.amazon.com/Android-NDK-Game-Development-Cookbook/dp/1782167781](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782167781) has pretty few things to do with Android NDK. However, it focuses on implementing a portable game engine from scratch in C++, regardless of the platform. Its topics mainly include low level things like filesystem, networking, audio and so on.